# Move many views against one another after collision iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, collision-detection, drag

I have been unsuccesfully trying to implement the following in my iOS application for the last few days

([Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aL0R-zOEPH0&feature=youtu.be))

[image]

**WHAT I WANT**

When any of these circles are dragged by the user (whether red or grey), the circles that come in contact with the moving one should move .
 So if all the circles were in a line and the first was moved to the right , it would push the rest of the circles to the right.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR**

1) `intersects(_ rect2: CGRect)` ***method***.   I couldn't think of anything else other than creating a huge number of nested for loops with the `intersects` method for every circle. *Firstly* , it looks very cluttery and *Secondly* the method is **inefficient** i.e. the method doesn't respond when the user drags too quickly .

2) `UICollisionBehaviour` . After reading in another question , I discoverd that this somehow only works when `UIDynamicAnimator` is responsible for moving Views on screen , NOT the user.(as with drag)

Finally I think , **Sprite Kit** is what I need , but I am not sure how or why  to use it for such a tiny component of my app.

Any suggestion would be aspirin. Thanks!

Comment: "After reading in another question , I discoverd that this somehow only works when UIDynamicAnimator is responsible for moving Views on screen , NOT the user.(as with drag)" No, you _can_ drag in a dynamic animator world.

Comment: But I tried and nothing happened. The views simply Superimpose each other . Can you point me to an example ?

Comment: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/61f0c753a080040e4a74b912e6c18dd97fe8bcaa/bk2ch05p204dragByAttachment/dragByAttachment/ViewController.swift But that is an example of dragging; I have to admit it doesn't try to do collisions while dragging, and you could be right, maybe that doesn't work. :(

Comment: Thanks Anyway .. I will try to find a way to do this with `UIDynamicAnimator` . If that doesn't I'll have to use `Sprite kit ` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to perform the **move against collision** effect using `Sprite kit` . It wasn't hard , as I had imagined.

This is however simply a proof of concept and doesn't address issues like being receptive to *super fast* movement.

If you are new to SpriteKit , go through [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/145318/spritekit-swift-3-tutorial-beginners) article from RayWenderlich.com . Ofcourse Apple's [Programming guide to Sprite Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html) 
is another amazing resource.

**CODE**

```
   class GameScene : SKScene

   var orangeBall : SKShapeNode!
   var greenBall  : SKShapeNode!

 // Description :  - Create two circular shapes here 
 //                - Give them physics bodies 
 //                - Add them  

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {




    orangeBall = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50 )                       // Size of Circle
    orangeBall.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)         // Middle of Screen
    orangeBall.glowWidth = 1.0
    orangeBall.fillColor = SKColor.orange

    orangeBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 50 )
    orangeBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    orangeBall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    orangeBall.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    orangeBall.physicsBody?.restitution = 1

    self.addChild(orangeBall)



    greenBall = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50 )                       // Size of Circle
    greenBall.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX + 70, y: frame.midY + 55.0 )         // Middle of Screen
    greenBall.glowWidth = 1.0
    greenBall.fillColor = SKColor.green

    greenBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 50)
    greenBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    greenBall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    greenBall.physicsBody?.density = greenBall.physicsBody!.density * 0.000001
    greenBall.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    greenBall.physicsBody?.restitution = 1

    self.addChild(greenBall)

}
```

***Configuring touch***

```
var fingerOnOrangeBall = false
var fingerOnGreenBall  = false


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

                if orangeBall.contains(touches.first!.location(in: self)){ fingerOnOrangeBall =  true }

                if greenBall.contains( touches.first!.location(in: self)){ fingerOnGreenBall =   true }



  }

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if fingerOnOrangeBall{

        let touch =      touches.first
        var position =   touch!.location(in: self.view)
        position =       self.convertPoint(fromView: position)
        orangeBall.position = position

    }

    if fingerOnGreenBall{

        let touch =      touches.first
        var position =   touch!.location(in: self.view)
        position =       self.convertPoint(fromView: position)
        greenBall.position = position

    }

}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

                   if   fingerOnOrangeBall { fingerOnOrangeBall =  false  }

                   if   fingerOnGreenBall {  fingerOnGreenBall =  false  }

}
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting back!

Comment: Don't mention it. :)

Comment: I still think dragging in dynamic animator can work, but I have not had time to try it.

Comment: Pushing and Dragging does work in the  `UIDynamicAnimator` . 
The trick was to call `animator.updateItem(UsingCurrentState...)`  every time the `view.center` updated , with `touchLocation`. 
However this solution was imperfect with a flickery view on every drag.
Also creating many  _draggable views_  was causing weird behaviour that I gave up to inspect.